# Alterar os estilos dos campos de formulários do Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, formulário

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de alterar os estilos de campos de formulário do bootstrap. Eu queria montar um formulário com um border-bottom e fundo transparente mas não consigo. alguém tem alguma solução?

Comment: Qual Boostrap 3 ou 4?  Vc quer fazer um form estilo Material Design só que com o Bootstrap? Edite a sua pergunta, coloque o que já tem de código ou o exemplo que está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acrescente uma classe `form-personalizado` onde você quer que tenha fundo transparente e borda e no css adicione isso

```
.form-personalizado{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00ff00;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

OBS: Seu input deve ter a classe form-personalizado ou não irá funcionar (`class="form-personalizado"`)

Comment: Otávio, muito obrigado...
Problema resolvido!

Comment: Fico contente em ajudar!

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar esses exemplos que tem mais abaixo nessa página da documentação do Bootstrap, tem uma classe especifica para fundo transparente.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
```